# Self-Test Support For Audiobooks

Tags: sonos

We are currently in the self-testing phase of developing a Sonos music API and encountered a issue with one of the test conditions, test_combinatorial_test_browse_to_leaf. Whenever we run the self-test, this test fails with an Instance message of "local variable 'response' referenced before assignment."

The structure of our content is very simple, with the root consisting of a list of mediaCollections of type "audiobook," each containing a list of mediaMetadata tracks. Our mediaCollections include tags for id, itemType, title, summary, author, narrator, canPlay and canResume (both always true), and albumArtUri.

We also looked into the test suite and found that the Instance message about "local variable 'response'" was due to the if-statement on ln. 57 of browse.py of the self-test code, which accounts for types TRACK, PROGRAM, and STREAM, but not AUDIOBOOK, leading to "response" never being assigned. Is this intended behavior or is this a bug in the self test suite?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the self-test suite. Please submit your service with your configuration file and we will work with you to resolve any issues as part of the application review process.